# Lagrange min/max issue when function is unbounded

Tags: calculus

Find max/min values for
$$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$
on the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -4xy = 1$ using Lagrange multipliers.

It seems that there may not be any due to the fact that we have an unbounded function. Am I thinking about this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the constraint is $(x-y)^2+z^2-2xy = 1$, and if we let
$p(t) = (t,t, \sqrt{1+2 t^2})$, then $f \circ p(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$
(and $p(t)$ satisfies the constraint). Hence no $\max$ exists.

Note that $(0,0,1)$ satisfies the constraint and the cost is the distance from the origin squared. Hence to determine if a $\min$ exists, we note that the constraint
$\|(x,y,z)\|^2 \le 1$ can be added without changing the (minimisation) problem. Since the constraint set is now compact we see that a $\min$ must exist so we can use Lagrange to find a solution. (It is straightforward to
check that the gradient of the constraint $(2x-4y,2y-4x,2z)^T$ is non zero at any point in the constraint, so the regularity condition is satisfied.)

The Lagrange condition for $z$ gives $2z+\lambda 2 z = 2z(1+\lambda) = 0$
hence either $z=0$ or $\lambda = -1$.

If $\lambda = -1$, then the conditions for $x,y$ gives $x=y=0$ from which we get $z = \pm 1$ with $f(0,0,\pm 1) = 1$.

If $z=0$, adding the conditions for $x,y$ gives $2(x+y)(\lambda -1) = 0$.
Hence $\lambda = 1$ or $x=-y$.

If $\lambda = 1$, we get $x=y$ and the constraint gives $-2x^2 = 1$ which is impossible, so we must have $x = -y$ in
this case. Solving gives the solutions $(\pm {1 \over \sqrt{6}}, \pm {1 \over \sqrt{6}}, 0)$ with cost $f(\pm {1 \over \sqrt{6}}, \pm {1 \over \sqrt{6}}, 0) = {1 \over 3}$.

Hence the $\min$ is ${1 \over 3}$.

Comment: I think this is perfect, except the Lagrange condition for z should be 2z MINUS lambda2z. The result is the same

Comment: The sign on $\lambda$ depends on the author, and can be absorbed into $\lambda$. It works out the same (other than sign).

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{1}{3}(3x^2+3y^2+3z^2)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(2x^2+2y^2+2z^2+4xy+x^2+y^2+z^2-4xy)=$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}((x+y)^2+z^2)+\frac{1}{3}\geq\frac{1}{3}.$$
The equality occurs for $x+y=0$, $z=0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2-4xy=1,$ id est, occurs,

which says that $\frac{1}{3}$ is a minimal value.

The maximal value does not exist because we can take $x=y\rightarrow+\infty$ and $z^2=1+2xy.$